# How to map the provide product ID in to the mailchimp account list?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

This is my input json

{

```
"id": "11378",

"customer": {
    "id": "112",
    "email_address": "freddie@freddiesjokes.com",
    "opt_in_status": true,
    "company": "SKU projects",
    "first_name": "firstname",
    "last_name": "lastname",
    "orders_count": 0,
    "total_spent": 0,
    "address": {
        "address1": "675 Ponce de Leon Ave NE",
        "address2": "Suite 5000",
        "city": "Atlanta",
        "province": "GA",
        "province_code": "30033",
        "country_code": ""
    }
},
"campaign_id": "7d613b7b31",
"checkout_url": "skuprojectsstg.prod.acquia-sites.com\/cart\/?checkout=11378",
"currency_code": "USD",
"order_total": 260,
"tax_total": 0,
"lines": [{
    "id": "45196",
    "product_id": "FWAX015",
    "product_title": "Waxed Canvas Bucket Bag",
    "product_variant_id": "FWAX015",
    "product_variant_title": "Waxed Canvas Bucket Bag",
    "quantity": 1,
    "price": 0
}]
```

}

The following JSON is while running the php code that executes the curl            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://us15.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/ecommerce/stores/SKU/carts');

{"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"detail":"A product with the provided ID does not exist in the account for this list.","instance":""}

Please help!! How to resolve this? What needs to be added ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says "A product with the provided ID does not exist".

Did you already create this product in a separate call before trying to make this request?  What happens if you do a simple GET request for a product with that ID?

I am working on adding Ecommerce to our cart with the API v3.0, and I created all our products before sending cart/order data--it doesn't automatically create them for you when you make a cart.